# Player Movement, Update too slow?

Tags: c#, class, vector, xna, sprite

I am trying to make a player collision system were the player will collide with an object that has been drawn on the screen. I use a pixle based system, I create 4 rectangles, top, bottom, left, and right. When any of them collide with that image the formula will check if the the rectangle and the block are intersecting and if so is the color intersecting.

Now this system that I use is so that I can create any type of image and it will work with out having to make a tile map. Let me take for example this block with a hole in the center:

[image: Black box with a hole in the center]

Now if the player is inside of the block the player will still collide with the block even though the player is inside the rectangle.

**But there is a problem.**

When I use a test map with some plate forms in side of the black box the idea works, kind of. The player does stop, and can move freely while the player still is inside of the rectangle, but the player sinks into the block a little before he stops.

*How do i fix this?

*I want to not use the rectangle collides into type of system and use this. Is there a better way?

*

**This is an example of how the intersecting pixels work. Using the bottom rectangle of the player and the Test Map.**

The method `IntersectPixels` needs two rectangles and two color data's; taking the rectangle of both the bottom rectangle and the image the player will collide into, as well as a `Color[]` for both of the images.

`public Rectangle bottomRectangle;`

`Rectangle mapRectangle;`

`Color[] mapColor;`

`Color[] bottomColor;`

First each rectangle must have a texture inside of it to work. So there needs to be two textures:

`Texture2D bottomTexture;`

`Texture2D mapTexture;`

Then by puting the texture and color for each image in an equation inside the LoadContent().

```
Color =
    new Color[Texture.Width * Texture.Height];
Texture.GetData(Color);
```

Then after both Rectangle and Color have the correct setup the `IntersectPixels` Method:

```
    static bool IntersectPixels(Rectangle rectangleA, Color[] dataA,
                                Rectangle rectangleB, Color[] dataB)
    {
        // Find the bounds of the rectangle intersection
        int top = Math.Max(rectangleA.Top, rectangleB.Top);
        int bottom = Math.Min(rectangleA.Bottom, rectangleB.Bottom);
        int left = Math.Max(rectangleA.Left, rectangleB.Left);
        int right = Math.Min(rectangleA.Right, rectangleB.Right);

        // Check every point within the intersection bounds
        for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
        {
            for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
            {
                // Get the color of both pixels at this point
                Color colorA = dataA[(x - rectangleA.Left) +
                                     (y - rectangleA.Top) * rectangleA.Width];
                Color colorB = dataB[(x - rectangleB.Left) +
                                     (y - rectangleB.Top) * rectangleB.Width];

                // If both pixels are not completely transparent,
                if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
                {
                    // then an intersection has been found
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // No intersection found
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Also, http://sscce.org/

Comment: I have restated my question and simplified it I am sorry for the extreme length of the last post and hopefully dumbed this down. I have just recently learned that there is a difference in collision detection and collision response and could be why it takes longer for the player to stop after hitting the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is first to check collision and then update position and draw. By this you can check collision one update position before it happend and you can in this case prevent updating position ... setting velocity ot 0 or anything else.